# SetAlpha doesn't make a difference usin RawImage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created a fade-in effect using SetAlpha for a Panel I'm using, which works fine:

```
public void AlphaManagement() {

        endGamePanel.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha (panelAlpha);
        Average.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha (panelAlpha);
        BestReaction.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha (panelAlpha);
        infoText.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha (gamePanelAlpha);

        if (amountOfTries == 10) {
            if (fade < 100) {
                panelAlpha += 0.01F;   
                gamePanelAlpha -= 0.1F;
                fade++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I've done the exact same thing with a series of RawImages:

```
public void AlphaManagement() {

        GraphBar1.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha(alpha);
        GraphBar2.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha(alpha);
        GraphBar3.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha(alpha);
        GraphBar4.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha(alpha);
        GraphBar5.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha(alpha);
        GraphBar6.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha(alpha);
        GraphBar7.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha(alpha);
        GraphBar8.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha(alpha);
        GraphBar9.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha(alpha);
        GraphBar10.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer> ().SetAlpha(alpha);

        if (oScript.amountOfTries == 1) {
            if (fade < 100) {
                alpha += 0.01F;
                fade++;
            }
        }
    }
```

However this doesn't work at all. I suspect it might be bacuse of it being a RawImage, but I'm insecure.

- If I change the alpha manually while my game is running, it is however working. Maybe I'm targetin the components alpha wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it after trying other UI components.

Raw Image seems to have issues using SetAlpha. I changed my UI components from RawImage to Panels and that solved my issue.